# exit() and header redirection not working in php after mpdf output after SSL

Tags: php, ssl, mpdf

Initially I was not working on secured server and everything was going fine. I was able to download PDF and then redirect to second page. My code is:

```
$mpdf->Output("$pdfname", "D");

header("Location:mypage.php");
```

and have tried:

```
 exit();
```

Now PDF can be downloaded, but after that redirection does not work. Any solution?
(Still my same code works fine in other server without SSL)

Comment: Redirection via `header()` won't work after the download because the HTTP headers will have already been sent by the PDF download.

Comment: exit() is already working in my other domain and header was working as well. The problem is with the new domain due to SSL